# Moderator Redaction flags does not display collapsed code snippets

Tags: bug, status-review, stack-snippets, moderator-tools, post-redaction

The moderator redaction tool does not display the redacted diff if the redacted bit was in a collapsed code snippet, so we cannot see what was redacted for approval. There aren't any buttons to expand the collapsed snippet.

[image]

Manually removing the class `snippet-currently-hidden` shows the snippet code.

[image]